# Nokogiri css selector contains isn't working all the time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

I wrote a script to extract the price from HTML:

```
sign = '$'

doc.css('*:contains("'+sign+'")').each do |element|
     #Code that i wrote that extract the price from a text
end
```

The problem is, for some sites Nokogiri finds all the elements that contain a dollar sign, and for some sites it doesn't find even one.

Example for site that it doesn't find even one element: http://www.urbanoutfitters.com/urban/catalog/productdetail.jsp?id=39101399&category=W-SOUTH

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The source of the page you linked does not contain a dollar sign. It seems to be added there by JS.

Comment: I can get the price from the urbanoutfitters site with `$('.mainPrice').text()` but `$('*:contains("'+$+'")').text()` returns an empty string

Comment: `$('span:contains("$")').first().text()`seems to work on this site

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for the answers.Mladen i'm taking the HTML manually after the page is rendered, i can see the price in the HTML.
and Harlem i want a generic solution, to write down the ID of the element will not solve my issue, also many website have a diffrence element for the price (div,p,span) so this is the reason i wrote *

Comment: What does taking the HTML manually mean? Also I think that's the wrong approach for trying to find a product's price.

Comment: Hey pguardiario, its means that affter the page is renderd i click view source ( or F12 ) and copying the HTML to a txt file and then open it on the script. what is the approach you recommend ?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Instead of a link to the entire page, we need the smallest HTML sample that demonstrates the problem in the question itself. Links age, rot, then break, and when it does your question won't make any sense to anyone else who's searching for a similar solution in the future.

Comment: You can't trust "view source" to show you what the source HTML contains. Browsers process the JavaScript prior to you being able to view the source and that can change the page, causing it to be different than the file on the server. Turn off JavaScript in the browser, then view the page, or, better yet, use `curl`, `wget` and an editor, or `nokogiri` at the command-line to retrieve the file, then look for what you are trying to find.

Comment: The link is dead. Can you update the link to an example?